# reactjs formik not passing values that gets set from the state

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form (sellform) this is imported into a component (sell component), inside the form when I set some fields dynamically then it won't be passed on the submit.

here are some snippets of what I tried:
in the sellcomponent:

```
return (
    <div>
        <SellForm
        initialValues={formValues}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        enableReinitialize      
        >
        Print   
        </SellForm> 
    </div>
);
```

in the sell form:

```
const calculate = (e) => {
    // let salePrice = parseFloat(inputs.salePrice);
    let salePrice = e.target.value;
    let calulatedTax = salePrice * 0.06;
    setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs, salesTax: calulatedTax}));
    console.log(inputs);
}
```

and:

```
 <FormGroup>
                <label for="salePrice">Sale Price</label>
                <Field name="salePrice" type="number"
                    className="form-control"
                    onBlur={(e) => calculate(e)}/>
                <ErrorMessage
                name="salePrice"
                className="d-block invalid-feedback"
                component="span"
                />
            </FormGroup>
```

and:

```
<FormGroup>
                <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax</label>
                <Field name="salesTax" type="number"
                    className="form-control" value={inputs.salesTax}/>
                <ErrorMessage
                name="salesTax"
                className="d-block invalid-feedback"
                component="span"
                />
            </FormGroup>
```

When I log the params that are being submitted back to the components the salesTax is empty, any ideas to try would be appreciated.
if any more details are needed please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass state values to initial values in formik in react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920132/how-to-pass-state-values-to-initial-values-in-formik-in-react-js)

Comment: Something feel off here because it looks like you have some `inputs` state in your own code, but with formik, all form state needs to be exclusively managed by formik. You are not actually using formik for its core capability at the moment. Its completely short-circuited because you manually pass a `value` prop. You need to let that be managed by formik and provide `name` only. You'd then call `setValues` from the formik context for the `calculate()` thing.

Comment: I tried setValues but never worked, do you have a good example? I am passing values from the component to the form, and initializing form values with the values passed then just trying to set some fields dynamically depending on other fields values